# Blackberry Delete SD Card files on deletion of app

Tags: blackberry

Ok this Blackberry App i have creates a database when installed and run first time. Its installed on the SD Card.

When I delete the app - this file remains and I cant find any way of deleting it at the time of app deletion.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application itself neither device OS do not do such actions. Upon unistalling an application only cod files are uninstalling and related persistent objects are removing. All generated data files (in device memory/media card) remain intact.

As an option to solve your task - implement and install additional application, i.e `uninstall watcher` or `uninstaller` that watches on uninstall event and removes all data files.

To utilize such functionality look for [CodeModuleManager class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/CodeModuleManager.html) and its method `addListener()`.

Implement [CodeModuleListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/CodeModuleListener.html) and pass its reference to `addListener()` method of CodeModuleManager.

And watch for deleting a particular module(s) and act accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no event about app uninstalling.

You could write, pack to resources (or download) and install second background application that will check your foreground application. In case  of foreground app deletion it will remove database and remove itself from the device. It's really advanced topic in the BB development.

If you want to hide data in database you could just encrypt it.